# Plot Additional Quantiles on Seaborn Violin Plots

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot

Using the example on [http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
```

[image: Violin plot]
<sub>(source: [pydata.org](http://seaborn.pydata.org/_images/seaborn-violinplot-2.png))</sub>

How can I draw two small horizontal lines on top of each violin (like the caps of error bars indicating the 2.5 percentile and the 97.5 percentile of the distribution?

Comment: couple of things: 1) the 2.5 and 97.5 percentiles of the data are not a confidence interval 2) just use the native `plot` method of the matplotlib Axes object (`ax`, in your case)

Comment: 1) Corrected, thanks! Sorry I was abusing the term slightly here... 2) I guess my problem is that I don't know how Seaborn handled categorical values on the x-axis. How do I know the x-value of "Thur", for instance?

Comment: Axes have a lot methods. Look up `ax.get_xlim()` for starters.

Comment: Thanks! I see that "Thur", "Fri", ... actually corresponds to range(3).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a rather hacky solution:

What about drawing another boxplot on top of your Violin plot? (And hiding the box in the box plot.)

Here is the output using 2.5 and 97.5:

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, showfliers=False, showbox=False, whis=[2.5,97.5])
sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually just figured out a similar solution, using ax.errorbar, but setting all line_widths to 0 so only the caps remain.

Comment: can you share how you used error bar without affecting the figure. When ever I use a error bar, the figure rooms line and I cannot control the x axis since they are just labels.